# Content div not filling a page, footer not aligned

Tags: css, html, height, footer

I have a page with a fixed height header, content (middle part) that should fill most of the screen until footer, and a fixed height footer that should stick to the bottom of the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/PyQed/

The problems I am having here are:

1. Content div (`#content-wrapper`) isn't filling the page, even though I set `min-height: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`, for `html` and `body` tags too.
2. Footer has a gap at the bottom instead of sticking to the very bottom of the page. Apparently the `body` element is not extending to the full height of the page, even though `html` does.

I followed the advice from [this page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) regarding how to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page, and it doesn't seem to work with my specific setup.

Comment: Did you take a look at [stickyfotter](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: The layout from that site does fix the footer gap problem (the `body` tag still seems to not fill the whole height of `html`, but the footer is positioned outside of `body`), but the `#content-wrapper` div still isn't filling the page. The `#body-inner` tag is, but I need the other inner div's to fill the page too, in order to horizontally center the fixed width content. Here is the forked example: http://jsfiddle.net/TLSdZ/1/ (there should be no pink visible).

Comment: You know you have a `height: auto !important;` in your css? That mean nothing can override that... So it doesnt take care of your `height: 100%`

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to be a hack for IE 6, which apparently needs to be put in a conditional comment. But `#content-body` is still not filling its parent: http://jsfiddle.net/3zTaF/1/

Comment: Yeah i know, was just pointing out, but seriously, I cant personally think of a clean way to do what you what without changing your HTML or using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/KFur6/517/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#divHeader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background:blue;
}
#divContent {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
    /*Allow for footer height*/
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:yellow;
}

#divPush {
    height: 30px;
}
#divFooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    /*Push must be same height as Footer */
    bottom:0;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Complete tutorial of this code is at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Ok, here is a fork from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/NJNjR/1/ I need the white div to extend all the way to the footer (I have a list inside of it that needs to fill the page to the footer).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Thanks! (It worked without spacers too, like this http://jsfiddle.net/tr8vT/1/)

Comment: Cool, glas to help. You may need the bottom spacer as the footer may overlap.